# Angular JS: Importing Sub Modules under a Main Module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, modularity, separation-of-concerns, angular-module

Definition:
Module: app, app.core (common services), app.widgets(common directives)
Components: Actual Controllers, Services, Directives definition

I have been working with separation of concerns and modularization of code with AngularJS and I came accross a weird thing which I am not sure why it was present.

I have defined all the **cross cutting components** of AngularJS App which can be reused by any modules under **app.core**

I have added other feature wise modules like **app.dashboard** and **app.admin** and both of these modules correspond to Dashboard View and Admin View.

All these modules fall under **app** module

app
   -app.core
   -app.widgets

-app.dashboard
   -app.admin

Dashboard and Admin view use the services and directives defined in app.core and app.widgets module.

Hence I go ahead and pour those modules in when I define my app.dashboard and app.admin as shown below

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.dashboard', [
        'app.core',
        'app.widgets'
      ]);

})();
```

The thing is code works properly when I write it like above or even if I **DO NOT ADD core and widgets**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.admin', []);

})();
```

**Above code also works fine**

What is the main difference between these 2?

Comment: You are not showing the whole code here. If your code in app.dashboard actually injects services from app.core or app.widgets, it will not explode. If your code in app.admin tries to inject a provider created in app.core, it will explode.

Comment: Module dependencies create sub-applications, and include their providers by name. You will notice the explosion when you declare some injections. As I see no controller or provider code here, I cannot be sure whether you're trying to inject something or not.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Can you check this link: https://github.com/ankittanna/angular-i18n-master and folder hottoweldone. You will get the entire code. app.core - common things usable across the app, app.widgets - common directives. app.dashboard - sub-app, app.admin - sub-app

Comment: I see the modules are disconnected. They do not inject anything from other modules, so it is the same depending on it or not, except that when the module is not present (declared beforehand), it will explode.

Comment: Dashboard and Admin use the logger services which are part of app.core module. How can they be disconnected?

Comment: oops you're right. let me check more code...

Comment: perhaps your app including both app.core and app.dashboard makes such injects available even when they do not depend directly (i.e. try to use app.dashboard as standalone app and you will boom).